# Trying to display custom colour picker

Tags: angularjs, html, color-picker

I am using angular directive to display the below colour picker

[image: here]

I am using directive code as below

```
    (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('ict')
        .directive('colorPicker', ['appConfig', '$rootScope', '$uibModal', '$state',
            function (appConfig, $rootScope, $uibModal, $state) {
                return {
                    scope: {
                        selectedColor: "=",
                        onColorChange: "&",
                        fillType: "="
                    },
                    templateUrl: 'app/partials/directives/color-picker.html',
                    link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
                        scope.colors = angular.copy(appConfig.colorPicker.basicColors);
                        if (!scope.selectedColor) {
                            scope.selectedColor = '#FFFFFF';
                        }
                        scope.changeColor = function (color) {
                            if (color) {
                                scope.selectedColor = color;
                            }
                            scope.onColorChange({ type: scope.fillType, color: scope.selectedColor });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]);
}());
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="color-pick-box r-item" uib-popover-template="'color-picker.html'"
     popover-class="custom-color-picker" popover-placement="bottom" popover-append-to-body="true"
     popover-trigger="outsideClick">
    <div class="picked-color" ng-style="{'background-color': selectedColor}"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="color-picker.html">
    <div class="color-input-section">
        <div class="color-input-box" ng-style="{'background-color': $parent.selectedColor}"></div>
        <div class="color-input-hex-field">
            <div class="title">HEX</div>
            <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.selectedColor" class="color-input" ng-change="$parent.changeColor()" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="basic-colors-box">
        <div class="color-box" ng-repeat="color in $parent.colors" ng-click="$parent.changeColor(color)" ng-style="{'background-color': color}">

        </div>
    </div>

</script>
```

and here is the usage

```
<div color-picker selected-color="ctrl.items[ctrl.selectedItemIndexes[0]].style.properties.backgroundColor" fill-type="'background'" on-color-change="ctrl.changeColor(type, color)"></div>
```

But, I need the colour picker to be shown as below where color can be selectable used different libs but none of them are worked

[image: here]

I am unable to show the colors with some selector(circle)

Comment: wrong tag, this belong in angularJS.Angular tag is used for Angular 2+.

Comment: @Asura Tag updated

Comment: This question **is not** widely applicable to a large audience. This is a particular problem of you. I'm talking about the bounty message btw

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search for 'angularjs color picker' came up with a list of libraries you could pick from. The first one, [angular-color-picker](https://github.com/ruhley/angular-color-picker), looks like exactly what you are looking for. The github has examples and demos detailing the available options and settings, but below is the quick start.

You need to include the css and js files required by this library. The github shows how to do this with bower or npm, or you can download the files from the github and add them directly to your project.

**app.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['color.picker']);
```

**.html**

```
<color-picker ng-model="myColor"></color-picker>
```